Draft R code that is replicating an existing VBA code, outputting different values ever so slightly
I am creating an R code from scratch that is replicating an existing model in VBA that loops over improvements using Newton Raphson several times until the output differences stabilise. As such any small rounding differences on what is being inputted into the start of the code end up causing it to fall over.
This is currently happening in that the inputs E are being brought in through read.excel on the original dataset in excel that the VBA uses. The values are for example 365318.425165619 and 313266.786807882 where they are displayed as 9 decimal places. Then in the R dataset that has been read in from these they are giving the values as 365318.42516561900266 and  313266.78680788201746 where they are displayed as 14 decimal places.
My question is that whether there is something in R that operates differently to excel and whether this is causing my calculation to fall over further down the calculations as the initial calculations seem to be fine.
For reference it is then used here in the alpha calculation that then gives slightly different output in the R dataset (-3.98568702613257741518, -3.98577596443294002171) compared to the VBA (-3.98568702613256, -3.98577596443293)
Alpha R Calculation Steps:
#creating dobj for alpha deviance
APCI_summary$dobj <- 2 * APCI_summary$weight * (APCI_summary$final_exposure * APCI_summary$m_xy - APCI_summary$calc_deaths)
dalphaobj_values <- aggregate(APCI_summary$dobj, by = list(APCI_summary$age), FUN = sum)$x
dalphaobj_m <- matrix(dalphaobj_values, nrow = length(dalphaobj_values), ncol = 1)

#creating d2obj for alpha deviance
APCI_summary$d2obj <- 2 * APCI_summary$weight * APCI_summary$final_exposure * APCI_summary$m_xy
d2alphaobj_values <- aggregate(APCI_summary$d2obj, by = list(APCI_summary$age), FUN = sum)$x
d2alphaobj_m <- diag(d2alphaobj_values)

#creating dobj and d2obj for alpha penalty
alpha_table <- data.frame(age = seq(age_min, age_max), alpha_x = APCI_summary$alpha_x[APCI_summary$year == year_max])
alpha_x_values <- alpha_table$alpha_x

# Convert the extracted column into a matrix
Alpha <- matrix(alpha_x_values, nrow = length(alpha_x_values), ncol = 1)
tAlpha <- t(Alpha)

dP_temp_alpha <- 2 * lambda_alpha * tDiff_3 %*% Diff_3 %*% Alpha

d2P_temp_alpha <- 2 * lambda_alpha * tDiff_3 %*% Diff_3

#combining dobj and d2obj respectively
dalpha_total_m <- dalphaobj_m + dP_temp_alpha
d2alpha_total_m <- d2alphaobj_m + d2P_temp_alpha

#final update step including the update to alpha values
d2Obj_inv <- solve(d2alpha_total_m) %*% dalpha_total_m
Alpha <- Alpha - d2Obj_inv
Alpha_data <- data.frame(age = seq(age_min, age_max), alpha_x = Alpha)

#then needs to update the calculation for this new Alpha value
APCI_summary <- APCI_summary %>%
  left_join(Alpha_data, by = "age") %>%
  mutate(alpha_x = coalesce(alpha_x.y, alpha_x.x)) %>%
  select(-alpha_x.x, -alpha_x.y)

APCI_summary$log_m_xy <- log_m_xy(APCI_summary$alpha_x, APCI_summary$beta_x, APCI_summary$year, APCI_summary$kappa_x, APCI_summary$gamma_x)
APCI_summary$m_xy <- exp(APCI_summary$log_m_xy)

APCI_summary$deviance <- APCI_summary$weight * (APCI_summary$calc_deaths * log(APCI_summary$calc_deaths)
                                                - APCI_summary$calc_deaths
                                                - APCI_summary$calc_deaths * log(APCI_summary$final_exposure * APCI_summary$m_xy)
                                                + APCI_summary$final_exposure * APCI_summary$m_xy)

Edit: this is also the VBA code it is trying to replicate which could possibly flag why it is falling over itself:
Private Sub ImproveAlpha(Lambda)

Dim X, Y, W, C, dlogm, X1, X2
Dim dObj(), d2Obj() As Double    ' first and second differentials of the Objective function
ReDim dObj(RP.MinAge To RP.MaxAge, 1 To 1)
ReDim d2Obj(RP.MinAge To RP.MaxAge, RP.MinAge To RP.MaxAge) As Double

' contribution from deviance
For X = RP.MinAge To RP.MaxAge
    For Y = RP.MinYear To RP.MaxYear
        W = RP.Weight(Y)
        C = Y - X
        If RP.MinCohort <= C And C <= RP.MaxCohort Then
            dlogm = 1
            dObj(X, 1) = dObj(X, 1) + 2 * W * (E(X, Y) * m(X, Y) - D(X, Y)) * dlogm
            d2Obj(X, X) = d2Obj(X, X) + 2 * W * (E(X, Y) * m(X, Y)) * dlogm ^ 2
        End If
    Next Y
Next X


' contribution from regularisation penalties
Dim Diff, P, dP, d2P, dP_temp

Diff = DifferenceMatrix(RP.NumAges, ORDERALPHA)
P = MMult(Transpose(Diff), Diff)

ReDim dP(RP.MinAge To RP.MaxAge, 1 To 1)
ReDim d2P(RP.MinAge To RP.MaxAge, RP.MinAge To RP.MaxAge)
dP_temp = MMult(P, VectorToMatrix(Alpha))


For X1 = RP.MinAge To RP.MaxAge
    dObj(X1, 1) = dObj(X1, 1) + 2 * Lambda * dP_temp(X1 + 1 - RP.MinAge, 1)
    For X2 = RP.MinAge To RP.MaxAge
        d2Obj(X1, X2) = d2Obj(X1, X2) + 2 * Lambda * P(X1 + 1 - RP.MinAge, X2 + 1 - RP.MinAge)
    Next X2
Next X1


' update the parameters
Dim Delta
Delta = MMult(MInverse(d2Obj), dObj)
For X = RP.MinAge To RP.MaxAge
    Alpha(X) = Alpha(X) - Delta(1 + X - RP.MinAge, 1)
Next X

End Sub


Almost certainly there are small differences in floating point calculations.  That's the nature of them!  But in the example you give, the 9 d.p. values match the 14 d.p. values exactly up to 9 d.p, so it's not clear what your problem is.

As I believe that they don’t go beyond the 9 d.p. So would be getting a loss of accuracy possibly?

There's always a loss of accuracy in floating point calculations using the 64 bit floating point representation that R uses.  You can only trust the first 15 or 16 digits (not decimal points, start counting from the first digit, so maybe 10 d.p. with numbers like yours).  I don't know what format Excel uses internally.  It is likely the same format, but it might be something else.  If your calculation is unstable because of differences that small, it will be hard to ever make it stable.

Furthermore, it's very hard to know (without lots of careful numerical analysis) which answer is 'more correct' (you could do the whole thing with arbitrary precision arithmetic in R, but that would be a lot of work ...). As a start, you would want to try to match up the starting values to the full precision of both systems (e.g. in R use print(..., digits = 22) or options(digits=22))
